# angular material 15 input status empty and has value

Tags: css, angular, input, angular-material, angular-daterangepicker

How can I set classes to check if input or date range picker has value or not.

Also, the placeholder in date picker not showing until the focus.

How can I fix that without adding extra TS code?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```js
<input [(ngModel)]="inputValue" [ngClass]="{'error': !inputValue}">
```